# PHP - ifless select by number

Tags: php

I would like to overwrite this function to if-less code:

```
function mapNumberToNames(float $number){
        if($number > 0 && $number < 25)
            return "A";
        if($number > 25 && $number < 50)
            return "B";
        if($number > 50 && $number < 75)
            return "C";
        if($number > 75 && $number <100)
            return "D";
}
```

do you have any idea how to write this function better? thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempts at doing this?

Comment: And you want to do this ... why?

Comment: Your code doen't handle the cases where `$number` is exactly equal to 25, 50, or 75.

Comment: How about `chr(ord("A")+(int)($number/25))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify both ends of each range. If you get past `if ($number < 25)` then the number must be `>= 25`, so you don't have to test that explicitly. This will prevent the problem in your code where you don't handle the conditions where the number exactly equals one of the boundaries (you should have used `>=` or `<=` in one of your tests).

Use `elseif` to test mutually exclusive conditions sequentially, and `else` for the final default.

```
function mapNumberToNames(float $number){
    if ($number < 25) {
        $grade = 'A';
    } elseif ($number < 50) {
        $grade = 'B';
    } elseif ($number < 75) {
        $grade = 'C';
    } elseif ($number < 100) {
        $grade = 'D';
    } else {
        $grade = 'F';
    }
    return $grade;
}
```

You could also put the mapping in an array.

```
function mapNumberToNames(float $number){
    $grade_map = [25 => 'A', 50 => 'B', 75 => 'C', 100 => 'D'];
    foreach ($grade_map as $limit => $grade) {
        if ($number < $limit) {
            return $grade;
        }
    }
    return 'F'; // default if nothing matched
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
switch(intval($number/25)) {
   case 0: return 'A';
   case 1: return 'B';
   case 2: return 'C';
   case 3: return 'D';
   default: return 'Z';
}
```

So just use the division result by 25 to avoid ifs.

Comment: I mean, that's fine in this very specific case, but change just one number and it's no good.

Comment: @PatrickQ what do you mean? If one needs a more generic case, you can just make a variable like `$divider = 25;` and use it.